# Metrization problem

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, metrizability

Can the following problem be solved by Nagata Smirnov metrization theorem,  which states that

> A topological space is metrizable if and only if it is frechet, regular and has a sigma locally finite basis.

It can be easily shown that it is frechet and regular but I can't prove the existence of a sigma locally finite basis.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried showing that $\mathcal{B}_n:=\{W_n(x)\mid x \in X\}$ is locally finite?

Comment: I tried but couldn't do that.

Comment: It’s enough to show $X$ is paracompact. That is covered in the text? Paracompactness, I mean?

Comment: Pg no. 126 chapter 4 metric space part 3 metrizability.

Comment: Use this link for the book. It's surely gonna work. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1slTd7uBl_mIJiN59L70WqnRl1mgrslwx/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Can anyone please help me

Comment: I saw you accepted an answer. So you have a proof now?

Answer (score 2):

The [original paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1937-43-02/S0002-9904-1937-06509-8/S0002-9904-1937-06509-8.pdf) for this result (stated on page 140) uses a theorem by Alexandroff and Urysohn quoted on p136 loc.cit. on metrization of Fréchet "voisinage"-spaces (a precursor to our modern topological spaces).

The modern version of this is in Engelking's *General Topology* as Thm 5.4.9 (the *Alexandroff-Urysohn metrisation theorem*, "the chronologically earliest metrization theorem"):

> A topological space $X$ is metrisable iff it is a $T_0$ space and has a [development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_(topology)) $\mathcal{W}_1, \mathcal{W}_2, \ldots$ such that for every $i \in \Bbb N$ and any two $W_1,W_2 \in \mathcal{W}_{i+1}$ such that $W_1 \cap W_2 \neq \emptyset$, there exists a $W \in \mathcal{W}_i$ such that $W_1 \cup W_2 \subseteq W$.

This in turn can be derived from *Moore's metrisation theorem*

> (a space $X$ is metrisable iff it is $T_0$ and has a strong development $\mathcal{W}_1, \mathcal{W}_2, \ldots$ (strong means that for every $x$ in $X$ and every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there is some $i \in \Bbb N$ and some open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\bigcup \{W \in \mathcal{W}_i\mid W \cap V \neq \emptyset\} \subseteq U$; for a normal development we just ask for $i$ such that $\bigcup \{W \in \mathcal{W}_i\mid x \in W\} \subseteq U$).

Moore's metrisation theorem in turn again can be quickly derived from *Bing's metrisation theorem* that

> $X$ is metrisable iff it's [collectionwise normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectionwise_normal_space) (including $T_1$) and has a development.

The last one has at least one proof based on Bing-Nagata-Smirnov.

So *yes* there is a proof based on B-N-S. Read Engelking's book section **5.4**, where all this is covered in detail. The notes and exercises to that section are informative (as to chronology, who proved what, and variations of such theorems).

Comment: Just for confirmation, are you saying that the problem in the question can be solved by using the given theorem in the question?

Comment: Is that proof is done by showing the existence of a sigma locally finite basis?

Comment: @Charlie yes, but it’s very roundabout. Only the last one mentioned uses the base. And Bing is the basis for the other ones again. And the paper shows ( in oldfashioned terminology) how to derive the result from A-U.

Comment: @Charlie is BNS the only tool in your text? What other general metrisability theorems are covered ?

Comment: if you look into the book "Introduction to general topology by Sze Tsen Hu" , the author just proved the given theorem which the only theorem related to metrization and gave this problem in the exercise. I don't know but I feel that it might be possible to prove the question using the given theorem directly.

Comment: In simple words it is the only tool in the text related to metrization

Comment: @Charlie Willard derives it from yet another metrisation theorem based on normal covers. Not from BNS.